# c# IText7 looping through text in PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

Currently we convert a bunch of pdf's to xlsx and then use vba to scrape through them for the data we need. I always get annoyed as all the pdf converters I've tried convert all documents differently which is rather annoying to deal with. So I had the bright idea to convert them myself in C#.

Using iText7 I can grab all the text and store it in a string using the code below but it's not extremely useful as I need to be able to loop through it and grab what I need.

```
public static string pdfTextExtract(string path)
    {

        var pageText = new StringBuilder();
        using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path)))
        {
            var pageNumbers = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
            
            //var lineNumbers = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPdfObjects();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumbers; i++)
            {
                LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
                var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
                pageText.Append( PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy));
                parser.Reset();
            }
        }

        return pageText.ToString();

    }
```

Hopefully someone can help me figure out how to loop through the pdf line by line rather than grabbing the whole page or how I can loop through the string nicely to grab names and figures.

Comment: How about splitting the string at newline characters and then looping through the resulting array?

Comment: Depending on the homogeneity of your PDFs, an alternative approach using iText could be to use [iText pdf2data](https://kb.itextpdf.com/2data/getting-started-with-itext-pdf2data) template-based data extraction, which could help you extract the data you need directly from the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Text in pdf files is not necessarily ordered in a logical way.
So the extracted text comes out of the text extractor in unexpected ways.

The [LocationTextExtractionStrategy](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/3b69a89bc8b72c2bc7147b210e886d4150379a68/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/listener/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.java) class has a method getResultantText, that outputs the text in topological order.

If you want to process the text line by line, you can use this result, or build your own  TextExtractionStrategy that outputs them line by line or through a stream.

By ordering the items topological it is even possible to detect tables columns and use a tab instead of a space to separate parts.